# Getting the co-ordinates of the highest point of the contour

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

After extracting the contour of the given image, I actually want to plot the highest on the contour indicated by a red circle in the image.

Image is:

[image]

My idea was to iterate through all the contour coordinates (x and y) and then select the highest y coordinate and corresponding x coordinate and plot it. 
But I am not sure whether this is the correct approach.

Code to plot all the points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX 
img2 = cv2.imread('Feature Extraction/images/Contour Detection Results/Result 2/Final_Image_with_Contour.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 

# Reading same image in another  
# variable and converting to gray scale. 
img = cv2.imread('Feature Extraction/images/Contour Detection Results/Result 2/Final_Image_with_Contour.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

# Converting image to a binary image 
# ( black and white only image). 
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

# Detecting contours in image. 
contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                               cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

# Going through every contours found in the image. 
for cnt in contours : 

    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True) 

    # draws boundary of contours. 
    cv2.drawContours(img2, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 1)  

    # Used to flatted the array containing 
    # the co-ordinates of the vertices. 
    n = approx.ravel()
    print(n)
    i = 0

    for j in n : 
        if(i % 2 == 0): 
            x = n[i] 
            y = n[i + 1] 

            # String containing the co-ordinates. 
            string = str(x) + " " + str(y)  

            if(i == 0): 
                # text on topmost co-ordinate. 
                cv2.putText(img2, "Arrow tip", (x, y), 
                                font, 0.1, (255, 0, 0))  
            else: 
                # text on remaining co-ordinates. 
                cv2.putText(img2, string, (x, y),  
                          font, 0.1, (0, 255, 0))

        i = i + 1

 Showing the final image. 
cv2.imshow('image2', img2)  

# Exiting the window if 'q' is pressed on the keyboard. 
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then I tried to make the coordinates of X and Y coordinates and append it to a list like:

```
xList = [x[0][0][0] for x in cnts]
yList = [y[0][0][1] for y in cnts]
```

When I try to plot this, I see nothing. 
How do I modify the code to find the desired point? I don't really understand what I am missing.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Edit 1:

[image]

Red Line indicates approximate curve which fits the contour.

Comment: Just to confirm, the image you've posted is the input image? the red circle is not an addition?

Comment: Yes, I have made the red circle with paint. I want to detect that coordinate. Should I post a new image without the red circle?

Comment: i ran your code on this image and I'm detecting 9 contours. I'm not sure if that's desirable.

Comment: I don't know why that is actually. Does that mean I cant find that coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the x and y coordinate, you need to use

```
xList = [x[0][0] for x in cnts]
yList = [y[0][1] for y in cnts]
```

`x[0]` gives you the tuple containing the x, y coordinates of the point and `x[0][0]` gives you the x coordinate, and `x[0][1]` gives you the y coordinate.

If you want the 'topmost' coordinate that you've circled, you'll need to do a lot more noise cleanup. Currently, the topmost point is going to the be the artifacts at the top edge of the image. A few morphological operations like `cv2.dilate()` and `cv2.erode()` could have helped but the target edge is quite thin, so it may distort the target edge..

[image]

The red lines show the contours that have been detected. Notice that the edge of the image has been selected as a contour because there are non-zero pixels on the edge of the image. You'll need to remove that noise to detect your desired top-most point. There's a lot of work to be done to get to your desired result.

Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX 
img2 = cv2.imread(r"/path/to/image", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 

# Reading same image in another  
# variable and converting to gray scale. 
img = cv2.imread(r"/path/to/image", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

# Converting image to a binary image 
# ( black and white only image). 
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

# Detecting contours in image. 
contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                               cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

# Going through every contours found in the image. 
for cnt in contours : 

    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True) 

    # draws boundary of contours. 
    cv2.drawContours(img2, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)  

    # Used to flatted the array containing 
    # the co-ordinates of the vertices. 
    n = approx.ravel()
    print(n)
    i = 0

    for j in n : 
        if(i % 2 == 0): 
            x = n[i] 
            y = n[i + 1] 

            # String containing the co-ordinates. 
            string = str(x) + " " + str(y)  

#            if(i == 0): 
#                # text on topmost co-ordinate. 
#                cv2.putText(img2, "Arrow tip", (x, y), 
#                                font, 1, (255, 0, 0))  
#            else: 
#                # text on remaining co-ordinates. 
#                cv2.putText(img2, string, (x, y),  
#                          font, 1, (0, 255, 0))

        i = i + 1

    xList = [x[0][0] for x in cnt]
    yList = [y[0][1] for y in cnt]
    print("x", xList)
    print("y", yList)

# Showing the final image. 
cv2.imwrite('image2.png', img2)
```

Comment: But when I try this, I get the following error: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: Regarding the topmost point, By using approxPolyDP() function, we get an approximate curve which best fits the contour. Can we use this curve somehow to find the topmost point? I will post another picture in the question of the image I am talking about.

Comment: this works fine for me. i run these two lines after the for loop.

Comment: Umm, not sure though. Did you write contours or cnts ? Because in my code which is in the question, I have written the lists with cnts but shouldn't it be contours? I just realized it now.

Comment: @yashrunwal I've added the code and some clarification. the code runs with no problems

Comment: Yes it works, My indentation was incorrect. So it is a lot of work! I have around 1000 such images. I was just trying with one image to see where I could get to. But do you think instead of getting the coordinates itself, we can draw a bounding box around it and get the coordinates of the bounding box? This was one more thing I could think of.

Comment: @yashrunwal I think that's up to you. Even if you detect the right contour, there are other points on the curve that are higher than the one you marked. I'm not sure what your usecase is, but this seems tough without a lot of noise removal.

Comment: Okay, I will try to check how to remove noise from this figure first